# Why cannot I attach a file in Android N+?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, email-attachments, android-7.0-nougat

I'm developing an App that is exporting some HTML tables as attachments. I have noticed that my code doesn't work if I try to attach the HTML table to Gmail, Google Drive, or any E-mail provider in Android N+, but it can upload the file to OneDrive, WhatsApp, Skype, etc. Without any issue.

This is my current code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
share.SetType("text/html");
share.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewDocument);

var file = CreateDirFile($"Meeting_{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss")}.html");

try
{
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fout.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr></table></body></html>"));
    fout.Close();
}
catch
{
    Toast.MakeText(context, context.GetString("Please check your storage configuration.").Show();
}

if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file.AbsoluteFile));
}
else
{
    share.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Path));
}
share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, $"Meeting {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}");
context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(share, "Email:"));
```

**CreateDirFile function:**

```
private Java.IO.File CreateDirFile(string fileName)
{
    string root = null;
    if (Android.OS.Environment.IsExternalStorageEmulated)
    {
        root = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        root = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    }

    Java.IO.File myDir = new Java.IO.File($"{root}/Meetings");
    myDir.Mkdir();

    Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(myDir, fileName);

    if (file.Exists())
    {
        file.Delete();
        file.CreateNewFile();
    }

    return file;
}
```

I have tested many combinations and even applied the following code `Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Path)` as it's suggested in different answers from SO or other forums, but it doesn't work as expected.

Have any of you experienced a similar issue? Do you know what should I change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't get to try this code but it should work. At least it has worked for me many times.

Add this code early enough in your onCreate method.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
    try{
        Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
        m.invoke(null);
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What this code does is that it disables the strict mode file uri rule in android api version 24 and above. This code was put in place to enforce the use of a FileProvider for applications that intends to share objects containing files via a public URI object. It turns out most time like many others it's an unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Despite Richard answer is the correct one in Java, there are some changes needed in C#, which are the following ones:

In the `OnCreate` event:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
{
    StrictMode.VmPolicy policy = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                        .PenaltyDeathOnFileUriExposure()
                        .Build();
    StrictMode.SetVmPolicy(policy);
}
```

Also, you need to have only this for the intent:

```
share.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file.AbsoluteFile));
```

You don't need to validate the OS version and this code `Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Path))` **must be removed** for the proper behaviour.